# Check function for 6 input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck at a check function for a project which includes 6 input fields with different answers.
So I have these inputs with the ids `input1` to `input6` and I need to validate answers which are the numbers: 2, 3, 2, 2, 4 and 4 again. `Input1` shall have the correct answer 2, `input2` shall have the correct answer 3... Also, if a user enters wrong answers in these fields, they shall reset by clicking on reset buttons only these wrong answers. The correct answers should remain validated. I have created an array with correct answers, but the `checkanswer()` function works only for the first input (id="input1") and I need to validate, after all inputs were completed. Also, I guess after validate should return an array with ids of inputs with wrong answers entered and this array must be added in the reset function.

Here's a fiddle with all code I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/66/

```
function checkAnswer(){    
    if(inputTF.value == "2") {        
        resetBtn.disabled = false
        checkBtn.disabled = true;  
        $('.feedback').show();
        updateBubble(3);
    } else {       
        updateBubble(2);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so as follows:

```
var response= []; // array for storing users responses
function checkAnswer() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value == raspunsuri[i]) {
        response.push(raspunsuri[i]); // if right ans, store the ans.
    } else {
        response.push(""); // if wrong ans, store empty string for clearing on reset
    }
  }
};

function reset(){ 
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
    inputs[i].value = response[i]; /*reset the textboxes from responses array,
                   where right answers are saved and wrong answers are empty strings */
  }
```

*side note: your fiddle has errors, it won't run.*

```
var raspunsuri = new Array["2", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4"]; //is invalid
var raspunsuri = ["2", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4"]; // valid
```

Comment: It doesnt help,from var raspunsuri, inputs should take its correct answer .getelementByTagName doesnt help coz my restrict function doesnt work then .It allow me to add more characters than 1 in input fields and even if i add correct answers in fields nothing happened :(

Comment: Damn...didnt checked the array with correct answers :( it works now.Thank you alot!